# Does it matter if i write "INTEGER" or "int" in sql command inside java?[sqlite]

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

When i execute sql commands, i.e. create table inside java code, does it matter if i write :

```
db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "scores int, "
                    + ");");
        }
```

Or this:

```
db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                        + "scores INTEGER,"
                        + ");");
            }
```

Or it is both same thing, just different syntax?

Comment: Which sqlite version?

Comment: Related: (SQLite version is important!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289410/difference-between-int-primary-key-and-integer-primary-key-sqlite/20289487#20289487

Comment: They both result in a column with INTEGER affinity. In fact, anything that contains the string "int" will do, including things that are not normally used as column types in SQL like "pr**int**er" or "t**int**edwindows" (no, this is not a joke)

Comment: @Karakuri: And to make things even more confusing, the column type “**floa**ting po**int**” has integer affinity because the “int” in “point” has precedence over “float”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sqlite3 documentation [says](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) if you use **INT** then the column has "resulting affinity" : **INTEGER**. Typenames *INT,  INTEGER,    TINYINT,    SMALLINT,   MEDIUMINT,  BIGINT, UNSIGNED BIG INT,   INT2,   INT8*  from the CREATE TABLE statement or CAST expression:  give **INTEGER** affinity for the column.

[For Sqlite2 see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20289487/1737819)

Comment: this answer is more detailed than mine , although it gives same link i gave in comment below. i will accept  it

Comment: Note that a column that's an alias of the ROWID (i.e., an `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` in a table that's *not* declared `WITHOUT ROWID`) is *required* to contain integers rather than merely having integer *affinity*.  This special case only applies when the type name is exactly `INTEGER`; an `INT PRIMARY KEY` is merely a normal integer-affinity column with a unique constraint.